# Laravel on shared host: safe method

Tags: php, security, laravel, deployment

Deployment of a Laravel 5 project shouldn't be done on a shared host, that's clear by now. But in some cases there's no alternative. I want to put my project online, but I need to make sure everything is safe and secure.

Is it a safe approach:

- Put all the content of the /public folder in the root
- All the rest in a /project folder

Is the public part separated enough from the "private" part of the app? Or are vulnerable files in danger? I'm fairly new to deploying Laravel projects, so this is the first time I will deploy a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No while those two folder still seperated its safe.

```
/home/username/public_html  -- public part
/home/username/laravaelAppSource -- private part with application
```

But to make it work you should change the index.php in public_html
/home/username/public_html/index.php

```
problem.require __DIR__.'/../laravaelAppSource/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```